# when I retrieve content from a sharepoint list nothing happen

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I'm using Javascript to retrieve items  from a sharepoint list.  But when I save  and checkin my page all my result disappear. could someone knows how to solve this please? 
I'am using sharepoint Online E1
Here's my code

```
    <script src="https://alpha.sharepoint.com/teams/intranet/Style%20Library/Cxpm/ajax_V1.js"></script>
<div id="divListItems"></div>

    <script>

    //alert("tets");
        $(function () {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
        });

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ephemeride');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

 //var t = new Array();
    var oListItem;
    var listItemInfo="";
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl; 
       oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        //Var obj = {Language: oListItem.get_item()};
        //if (obj.Language=='Fr')
            //continue;

        listItemInfo +='\n' +'<br />' + 

        ' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '<br />' +      
        ' <strong>Content:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Content')  +

         ' <strong>Location:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Location') + '<br />' +

        ' <strong>Link:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Link').get_url()+

        '<br />';

        //t.push([oListItem.get_item,oListItem.get_item('Variable'),oListItem.get_item('Value')]);
    }
    //alert("tets");
    $("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);
    //document.getElementById("domo").innerHTML="zone1*zone2";
    //alert("tets");

}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Replace this line `$(function () {
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
});` and instead use `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);` and check

Comment: still no working

Comment: @Raise Are you getting any error in browser console ??

Comment: I just don't have no results.  In my console I have this error message SCRIPT5009: 'collListItem' is undefined

Answer (score 1):

**First,** `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` is not working with **Publishing Page**, so you should instead use `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', yourfunction);` .

To test this, try the below code in your script editor (In Publishing Mode)

```
<button onclick="SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CheckPublishingPage);"> Test Script Excution in Publishing Page </button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckPublishingPage()
{
alert("Check Script in Publishing Page");
}
</script>
```

**Second,** I have noticed that you have used `<script>` tag without setting its type `type="text/javascript"`, this may cause an issue in case the `Minimal Download Strategy` feature activated.

**Third,** I tested your code and not working for me in `Check-In` Mode or `Publishing` Mode!!!

So, I have customized the below code that tested and worked properly in both modes!

```
<div id="divListItems">M.Qassas</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
});

function retrieveListItems() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ephemeride');  
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(this.collListItem);        
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = this.collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
     listItemInfo +='\n' +'<br />' + 

        ' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '<br />' +      
        ' <strong>Content:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Content');
}
document.getElementById("divListItems").innerHTML=listItemInfo;

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

**{OutPut}**

[image]

Comment: Tkx M.Qassas, but you code doesn't disply anything. Are you using Sharepoint online?

Comment: Yes and worked for me as shown in screebshoot!! and make sure you have provided you information, another thing make sure you are using https for <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: The problem is from here : $(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
});

Comment: bro, Could you try this first `<button onclick="SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CheckPublishingPage);"> Test Script Excution in Publishing Page </button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckPublishingPage()
{
alert("Check Script in Publishing Page");
}
</script> ` to make sure that the script is working in Publishing Page

Comment: Yes It's working.

Comment: But the other code still not working atfer saving it

Comment: Do you try to use https instead of http in jquery link!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68647/discussion-between-raise-and-m-qassas).

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code into a script editor web part to check if it works.

```
<div id="divListItems"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ephemeride');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var oListItem;
    var listItemInfo="";
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl; 
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo +='\n' +'<br />' + 
            ' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '<br />' +      
            ' <strong>Content:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Content')  +
            ' <strong>Location:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Location') + '<br />' +
            ' <strong>Link:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Link').get_url()+
            '<br />';      
    }
    $("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +'\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Are you using sharepoint online? or sp onprem?

Comment: I use the code in script editor web part in SharePoint Online classic experience, if you use in modern UI, the code will not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your code **CamlQuery is missing**.

Depending on query only item can retrieve from SharePoint List either JavaScript or Rest API or JQuery.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ephemeride');    
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);        
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nContent: ' + oListItem.get_item('Content') +
        '\nLocation: ' + oListItem.get_item('Location') +
        '\nLink: ' + oListItem.get_item('Link').get_url();
}
alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any issue because of CAML query missing. Just for information, if we just initializes a new instance of the `SP.CamlQuery` without the `camlQuery.set_viewXml` (i.e. undefined CamlQuery object), we get all the items from SharePoint list....Refer this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx